# Sugar alternative when beating eggs and sugar together

Tags: baking, substitutions, sugar

If I wouldn't want to use refined white sugar in recipes warranting sugar and eggs beaten fluffy, what would be the best alternative to use? Would the result be very different?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the types of recipes you're talking about? The first thing I think of when you say "beating sugar and butter" is cookies but you need to be very specific because the answer will depend on what you're making.

Comment: Sorry, I meant eggs instead of butter. I am thinking of custard for ice cream and sugar bread (for layered cakes) primarily.

Comment: Is it refined white sugar you want to avoid, or sugar in general?

Comment: refined, but I'd be curious to know if there are alternatives to sugar altogether too.

Comment: Molasses might prove interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the chemical and mechanical reactions between egg-white, egg-yolk and sugar is quite an delicate and complex one. I find that there is even a difference in using white refined cane sugar and white refined beet sugars when baking and the amount of effort of creaming eggs and sugar. Sugar substitutes that claim that they "behave" the same as sugar also don't seem to react in a manner that you'd expect.

I would suggest that you try a range of sugars... The worse of them seems to be corn based sugars. The eggs just don't behave at all...

Answer (score 0):

Use maple sugar.

Things will taste better*, but cost more.

*unless, of course, you are a person who does not like real maple (of whom there are a surprising number, though I cannot claim to understand that.)

For ice cream/sorbet/gelato/frozen desserts, most "sugar substitutes" (low calorie sweeteners, etc) don't really work, as sugar plays an important structural role in how ice cream turns out. Being sugar, maple sugar (or other "unrefined/less refined" sugars) work fine.